# How to obtain a fbid list from fbapi2.0 without accessToken

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

i  need to map the same person's fbID between the old app(fb1.0) and new app(fb2.0)
Can i get the fbid list via a http request without accessToken??

That means i want to pull the fbid list with both my appkey & a user's fbid.

Answer (score 0):

In order to match User IDs between different Apps, you need to use the Business Mapping API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Consider reading the v2.2 changes of the changelog too:

> A new token_for_business field makes it easier to identify the same person across multiple apps owned by the same business

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

For getting details (or just the ID) of a User, you always need an Access Token.

Comment: GET /me/ids_for_business HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com

Comment: First i want to confirm that is it possible to get the response without access_token or any other authorizations . & can you give me an example of this complete request? I've tried several times but fail to get the correct response.  thx

Comment: you cannot get any user details without an access token, of course. you need a user token for getting the id of a user.

Comment: That means i can`t distinguish the same user between the old app and the new app..

Comment: I think it's really irrational..Thx for answer my question..It helps a lot

Comment: you can, with the business mapping api, see the link in my answer. i will add some more information.